# Rails form_for Can not save database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm newbie and need help on reviewing my code.
The form data can't be saved and flash success message is not showing either.
this is what's showing up in rails server:

```
Started POST "/registrations" for 139.193.122.192 at 2016-01-18 02:02:07 +0000 
Cannot render console from 139.193.122.192! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255 Processing by RegistrationsController#create as HTML   
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"rOZfP2y2huPWAZoUaYjlRXyos5aqiaJh3MTiidXZFRBHJW0yL/rSC4cZwyMuZ//UwwUounNMgzL8HL/yJI8RyQ==", "registration"=>{"name"=>"Yosafat", "last_name"=>"Kakomba", "date_of_birth"=>"06/08/1982", "address"=>"Perum Vila Nusa Indah 2 Blok CC2/18 Jatiasih", "suburb"=>"Bekasi", "post_code"=>"16969", "telephone"=>"622193709536", "email"=>"ariel.kakomba@gmail.com", "news_letter"=>"1", "private_health_fund"=>"0", "exercise_routine"=>"Never", "occupation"=>"Programmer", "past_medical_history"=>"I don't have", "medication"=>"I don't have", "symptoms"=>"I don't have", "terms_of_service"=>"1"}, "gift_voucher"=>"1", "other_references"=>{"{:placeholder=>\"Do you have any other references?\"}"=>""}, "gentle_treatment"=>"1", "head"=>"1", "allergies_or_asthma"=>"1", "commit"=>"Register Now"} 
Unpermitted parameter: last_name    (0.1ms)  begin transaction   Registration Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "registrations" WHERE LOWER("registrations"."email") = LOWER('ariel.kakomba@gmail.com') LIMIT 1    (0.1ms)  rollback transaction Redirected to https://simpleform3-yoskakomba.c9users.io/ Completed 302 Found in 192ms (ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)


Started GET "/" for 139.193.122.192 at 2016-01-18 02:02:07 +0000 Cannot render console from 139.193.122.192! Allowed networks:
    127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255 Processing by PagesController#index as HTML   Rendered pages/index.html.erb within layouts/application (37.3ms)   Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (2.3ms)   Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms) Completed 200 OK in 309ms (Views:
    308.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

and when I checked in Rails Console:
The data is not saved, and flash success message is not showing up.

**Here is my controller:**

```
class RegistrationsController < ApplicationController
  def new 
    @registration = Registration.new  
  end

  def create 
    @registration = Registration.new(registration_params)

    if @registration.save
      flash[:success] = "Your registration was created succesfully"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  private

  def registration_params
    params.require(:registration).permit(:name, :lastname, :date_of_birth,
    :address, :suburb, :post_code, :telephone, :private_health_fund,
    :email, :reference, :news_letter, :occupation, :exercise_routine, :body_conditions,
    :past_medical_history, :medication, :symptoms, :other_experience, :preference, 
    :body_area, :terms_of_service, :drive_and_walk_by, :google_search,    :gift_voucher, :yellow_pages, :yelp, :trip_advisor,:start_local,
    :tenbest, :time_out, :friend_referral, :quiet, :treatment_description, :gentle_treatment, :face,
    :hair_scalp, :head, :chest, :stomach, :back, :buttocks, :arms, :legs, :hands, :feet, :allergies_or_asthma, :open_wounds,
    :numbness_tinglint,
    :skin_condition, :headaches_migraine, :recent_illness_or_surgery, :varicose_veins, :diabetes, :osteoporosis)
  end

end
```

**the form is in index.html.erb and using *ClientSideValidation* gem to validate**

```
<h2>Registration Form</h2> <hr>

<div class="row">
    <div class="well col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

      <%= form_for @registration, validate:true do |f| %>

      <div class="row"><!-- FIELD FOR NAME / LAST NAME / DOB -->

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <%= f.label :name %>
          <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: 'first name' %>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <%= f.label :last_name %>
          <%= f.text_field :last_name, placeholder: 'last name' %>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <%= f.label :date_of_birth %>
          <%= f.text_field :date_of_birth, placeholder: 'Your date of birth ex: DD/MM/YYYY' %>
        </div>
        </div>

  <div class="row"><!-- FIELD FOR ADDRESS / SUBURB/ POSTCODE -->

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <%= f.label :address %>
      <%= f.text_field :address, placeholder: 'Your primary home address' %>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <%= f.label :suburb %>
      <%= f.text_field :suburb, placeholder: 'Your sub urban area' %>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <%= f.label :post_code %>
      <%= f.text_field :post_code, placeholder: 'Address postal code' %>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="row"><!-- FIELD FOR TELEPHONE AND EMAIL -->

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <%= f.label :telephone %>
      <%= f.text_field :telephone, placeholder: 'Mobile or landline' %>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, placeholder: 'Your email address' %>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="row checkbox"><!-- FIELD FOR PRIVATE HEALTH FUND & NEWSLETTER CHECKBOX -->

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <%= f.label :news_letter %>
      <%= f.check_box :news_letter %> 
      <p>*Interested in receiving news or promotion from us?</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
     <%= f.label :private_health_fund %>
     <%= f.check_box :private_health_fund %>
     <p>*Do you have private health fund?</p>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="row"></div>

  <div class="row checkbox"><!-- FIELD FOR REFERENCES AND PREFERENCE -->

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <b>How Did You Hear About Us?</b><br/><br/ >
      <%= check_box_tag :drive_and_walk_by %> <h8>Drive and Walk by</h8> <br/>
      <%= check_box_tag :google_search %> <h8>Google Search</h8> <br/>
      <%= check_box_tag :gift_voucher %> <h8>Gift voucher</h8> <br/>
      <%= check_box_tag :yellow_pages %> <h8>Google Search</h8> <br/>
      <%= check_box_tag :yelp %> <h8>Yelp</h8> <br/>
      <%= check_box_tag :trip_advisor %> <h8>Trip Advisor</h8> <br/>
      <%= check_box_tag :start_local %> <h8>Start Local</h8> <br/>
      <%= check_box_tag :tenbest %> <h8>10Best</h8> <br/>
      <%= check_box_tag :time_out %> <h8>Time Out</h8> <br/>
      <%= check_box_tag :friend_referral %> <h8>Friend referral</h8> <br/><br/>
      <b>Other References</b><br/>
      <%= text_field :other_references, placeholder: 'Do you have any other references?'%>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <b>Your Preference in Massage Therapy</b><br/><br/ >
      <%= check_box_tag :quiet %> <h8>Quiet environment</h8> <br/>
      <%= check_box_tag :treatment_description %> <h8>Treatment Description</h8> <br/>
      <%= check_box_tag :gentle_treatment %> <h8>Gentle Treatment</h8> <br/><br/>
      <b>Excercise Routine</b><br/>
      <%= f.select :exercise_routine, ['Never', 'Light 1-2 times', 'Moderate 3-4 times', 'Competitive 5-7 times'], validate: false, prompt: 'How many times do you excercise?' %>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="row checkbox">

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <b>Body area you want to skip</b><br/><br/ >
      <%= check_box_tag :face %> <h8>Face</h8> <br/>
      <%= check_box_tag :hair_scalp %> <h8>Hair Scalp</h8> <br/>
      <%= check_box_tag :head %> <h8>Head</h8> <br/>
      <%= check_box_tag :chest %> <h8>Chest</h8> <br/>
      <%= check_box_tag :stomach %> <h8>Stomach</h8> <br/>
      <%= check_box_tag :back %> <h8>Back</h8> <br/>
      <%= check_box_tag :buttocks %> <h8>Buttocks</h8> <br/>
      <%= check_box_tag :arms %> <h8>Arms</h8> <br/>
      <%= check_box_tag :legs %> <h8>Legs</h8> <br/>
      <%= check_box_tag :hands %> <h8>Hands</h8><br/>
      <%= check_box_tag :feet %> <h8>Feet</h8><br/>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <b>Existing Health Condition</b><br/><br/ >
      <%= check_box_tag :allergies_or_asthma %> <h8>Allergies or Asthma</h8> <br/>
      <%= check_box_tag :open_wounds %> <h8>Open Wounds</h8> <br/>
      <%= check_box_tag :numbness_tinglint %> <h8>Numbness/Tinglint</h8> <br/>
      <%= check_box_tag :skin_condition %> <h8>Skin Condition</h8> <br/>
      <%= check_box_tag :headaches_migraine %> <h8>Headaches/Migraine</h8> <br/>
      <%= check_box_tag :recent_illness_or_surgery %> <h8>Recent Illness or Surgery</h8> <br/>
      <%= check_box_tag :varicose_veins %> <h8>Varicose Veins</h8> <br/>
      <%= check_box_tag :diabetes %> <h8>Diabetes</h8> <br/>
      <%= check_box_tag :osteoporosis %> <h8>Osteoporosis</h8> <br/><br/>
    </div>

  </div><br/>

  <div class="row"><!-- FIELD FOR OCCUPATION AND PAST MEDICAL HISTORY -->

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <%= f.label :occupation %>
      <%= f.text_area :occupation, placeholder: "Your main job", validate: false %>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <%= f.label :past_medical_history %>
      <%= f.text_area :past_medical_history, placeholder: "Please tell us if you have medication history within 5 years before we proceed your therapy",
      validate: false %>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="row"><!-- FIELD FOR MEDICATION AND SYMPTOMS -->

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <%= f.label :medication %>
      <%= f.text_area :medication, placeholder: "Please tell us if you have medication history within 5 years before we proceed your therapy",
      validate: false %>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <%= f.label :symptoms %>
      <%= f.text_area :symptoms, placeholder: "Please tell us if you have any symptoms regarding your existing health condition before we proceed your therapy", validate: false %>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <b>Terms Of Service</b><br/>

      <h7>Arrival Time</h7>
      <p>Please arrive at least 10 minutes before your treatment. New clients will be asked to fill out a record form.</p>
      <h7>Arrival Late</h7>
      <p>All treatments conclude at the scheduled time.</p>
      <h7>Cancelation Policy<h7>
      <p>When you reschedule or cancel an appointment, we require 24 hours notice; cancellation without notice will incur a cancellation fee of $30.
      Confirmation of an appointment is acknowledgement of this cancellation policy.</p>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 checkbox">
      <%= f.label "I agree with the terms of service" %>
      <%= f.check_box :terms_of_service %><br/>
      <p>*I read and understood the terms of service</p>

    </div>
  </div>
      <%= f.submit 'Register Now', class: "btn btn-success" %>

  <% end %>

</div><!-- FIELD FOR CLASS WELL -->
```

```
**This is my *application.html.erb***
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Workspace</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
  <%= render 'layouts/navigation' %>
  
  <div class="container">
    <%= render 'layouts/messages' %>

    
    <%= yield %>
    

    <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

**This is my registration.rb**

```
class Registration < ActiveRecord::Base   validates :name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 19 }   validates :last_name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 19 }   validates :address, presence: true   validates :date_of_birth, presence: true   VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A([\w+\-].?)+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 105 },
                                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false },
                                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }   validates :suburb, presence: true   validates :state, presence: true   validates :post_code, presence: true   validates :telephone, presence: true   validates :reference, presence: true   validates :news_letter, presence: true   validates :occupation, presence: true   validates :exercise_routine, presence: true   validates :body_conditions, presence: true   validates :past_medical_history, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 500 }   validates :medication, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 500 }   validates :symptoms, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 500 }   validates :other_experience, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 500 }   validates :preference, presence: true   validates :body_area, presence: true   validates :terms_of_service, presence: true    end
```

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: "I'm newbie and need help on reviewing my code." - Welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're new, I have some suggestions (`@Pavan`'s answer is correct).

---

The reason you've got the problem is because you're *requiring* `:last_name` to be present with a [validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence):

```
#app/models/registration.rb
class Registration < ActiveRecord::Base
      validates :name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 19 } 
      validates :last_name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 19 }
      validates :address, presence: true
      validates :date_of_birth, presence: true VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A([\w+\-].?)+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
      validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 105 }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }   
      validates :suburb, presence: true
      validates :state, presence: true   
      validates :post_code, presence: true
      validates :telephone, presence: true
      validates :reference, presence: true
      validates :news_letter, presence: true
      validates :occupation, presence: true
      validates :exercise_routine, presence: true
      validates :body_conditions, presence: true
      validates :past_medical_history, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 500 }
      validates :medication, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 500 }
      validates :symptoms, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 500 }
      validates :other_experience, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 500 }
      validates :preference, presence: true
      validates :body_area, presence: true
      validates :terms_of_service, presence: true
end
```

Although this is great, it means that if you don't pass that parameter, Rails will come back with an error. Errors are stored in the `errors` method attached to your returned object:

```
#app/views/registrations/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @registration do |f| %>
   <% if @registration.errors.any? %>
      <% @registration.errors.full_messsages do |message| %> 
          <%= message %>
      <% end %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This will return the error messages from your model.

```
#app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb
class RegistrationsController < ApplicationController
   def create 
      @registration = Registration.new(registration_params)
      redirect_to root_path, success: "Your registration was created" if @registration.save
      # will render "new" if errors
  end
end
```

---

Secondly, you can clean up your model massively by declaring multiple validations (if they're the same):

```
#app/models/registration.rb
class Registration < ActiveRecord::Base
      VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A([\w+\-].?)+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i

      validates :name, :last_name,     presence: true, length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 19 } 
      validates :email,                presence: true, length: { maximum: 105 }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }   
      validates :past_medical_history, :medication, :symptoms, :other_experience, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 500 }
      validates :date_of_birth, :address, :suburb, :state, :post_code, :telephone, :reference, :news_letter, :occupation, :exercise_routine, :body_conditions, :preference, :body_area, :terms_of_service, presence: true
end
```

---

Thirdly, your model needs to be called by the object name it reflects.

Ruby is an [*object orientated*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) language, which means that everything you do with the system should be scoped around objects.

As a beginner, this won't matter; as you progress, you'll realize the importance of having...

```
@user = User.find x
@user.do_some_action
```

... thus, when you have `Registration`, if that's the nature of the data you're storing, it's great. If it *isn't*, you'll be best suited changing its name to something like `User` or `Applicant` etc.

---

Lastly, you need to cut down on all the data you're storing in *one* model.

You can split your model into about 2 others:

```
#app/models/registration.rb
class Registration < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :address
   has_one :preference
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, :preference
end

#app/models/address.rb
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :registration
end

#app/models/preference.rb
class Preference < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :registration
end
```

This will allow you to pass multiple sets of data, rather than keeping it all in the same model:

```
#app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb
class RegistrationsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @registration = Registration.new
      @registration.build_address
      @registration.build_preference
   end
end

#app/views/registrations/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @registration do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :address do |a| %>
      <%= a.text_field :address %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You can [read up more about `accepts_nested_attributes_for` here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Rich, I'm going to fix it based on your review. I really didn't notice that before.

Comment: Hi Richard, your answer has helped me solved my previous problem.
I have question about heroku deployment here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36050505/rails-deployment-to-heroku-is-showing-error if you don't mind helping me with your review.

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Certainly, let me see what's up!

Answer (score 3):

When you look into the log that you posted, you can see there is an `Unpermitted parameter: last_name`. This is because in the form you have `last_name` and in the `registration_params` method you have `lastname`.

Changing `lastname` to `last_name` in `registration_params` should solve your problem.

Comment: Hi Pavan, thanks for showing me the errors on "Unpermitted parameters", I didn't notice that.
I already changed it in registration_params.

Comment: @ArielBoham If my answer has worked for you, please accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you have missed some of your form code but there needs to be

```
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

..also, your flash messages are working in the background but you need to create a place for them to show up. Go to your application.html.erb in your layouts folder and after the opening body tag add:

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
      <%= content_tag :div, value, class: "#{key}" %>
<% end %>
```